# Why the Facebook PHP SDK is out of date? What is the alternative?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I'm so frustrated right now. I spent so much time trying to debug my application to find out that the official PHP SDK from Facebook is out of date and doesn't look like it's maintained anymore: https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk

After lodging a bug to Facebook because of an error returned by the API, one of the employee at Facebook respond the following:

> THe old REST API does not support use of Page Access Tokens, you need to use the Graph API for such API calls - if you're using an SDK, please ensure it's routing your FQL queries to https://graph.facebook.com/fql?q=X and not https://api.facebook.com/method/fql.query

However in the PHP SDK that Facebook provide it's using the following request:

```
URL: https://api-read.facebook.com/restserver.php
GET: method=fql.query&return_ssl_resources=1&query=SELECT+comment_info.comment_count%2C+created_time%2C+like_info.like_count%2C+permalink%2C+post_id%2C%0A+share_info.share_count%2C+type%2C+attachment.media%0A+FROM+stream%0A+WHERE+actor_id%3Dxxxxxx%0A+AND+source_id%3Dxxxxxx%0A+ORDER+BY+created_time+DESC%0A+LIMIT+100&callback=&api_key=xxxxxxxxx&format=json-strings&access_token=xxxxx
```

Anyone bumped into this issue? What SDK are you using instead?

Comment: The message already tells you that you can easily make FQL queries with the SDK using the syntax `fql?q={query}`, so what’s your actual problem?

Comment: It's what I've ended up doing. However all the documentation, example, etc. are referring to the wrong way to do it. Nowhere I've seen someone using the `fb::api('/fql', $params)` syntax. I'm guessing I don't have a problem if I don't follow the official Facebook PHP SDK documentation.

Answer (score 1):

The PHP SDK on Github is still maintained and the official source (see https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/)

Still, old API (like the REST api) are still supported for backward compatibility concerns. But for new stuff, you need to use the Graph API. If you read the documentation, it is very clear that the Graph API is the way to go (there's no mentions of REST api in the documentation). https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/facebook-api/

So, I think the issue here is you started of reading some old blog posts without reading the official APIs docs. Honestly, around Facebook stuff, only believe what you can find in the official documentation and on StackOverflow with a good vote rating. Too many bad developers have been trying to bring SEO to their websites writing shitty article on developing Facebook apps.

Comment: Thanks Simon. This is not old blog stuff, this is from the actual documentation, ie. `FQL Queries`, the example they provide specifying the method `fql.query` this will translate by the `restserver.php` call. Which is working time to time but not recommended by Facebook. If you dump the `URL` and `postData` in `makeRequest()` you'll see by yourself.

Comment: You have a link to the documentation page? FQL usually works on top of the Graph API too, so I'm a bit surprise by what you say.

Comment: The same link you provided: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/facebook-api/ the example at the end of the doc.

Comment: Just try a simple `fql` query using `fb::api(array('query'=> '...', 'method'=>'fql.query'))` and you'll see that it's calling the `restserver.php` URL.